# Ruta de windows para el mountpoint de un volumen (Docker)

Tags: windows, docker

He visto en este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTeDNXLFYjE&feature=emb_logo que el mountpoint de los volúmenes puede tener una dirección dentro del sistema de archivos de Windows.

Mi problema es que por mas que yo intente cambiar cosas, la ruta del mountpoint es siempre la misma, una ruta de Linux.
[image: Captura mountpoint]

Yo instale Docker usando DockerDesktop y al momento de instalarlo tenia WSL2, más tarde instale el Hyper-V de Windows.

Mi sospecha es que la configuración predeterminada ya dicta que los volúmenes se guarden en Linux pero cuando ejecuto WSL desde la consola no puedo encontrar esa ruta.
[image: Captura WSL]

Necesito configurar Docker para que por defecto cree los volumenes en una ruta dentro de Windows.